# Restricting search on certain columns in jquery dynatable

Tags: jquery, dynatable

How can I enable search only for certain columns in [dynatable](http://dynatable.com/)? Right now it is searching in whole record, I have some urls as well in the data which have common part of strings as in the record of one column.

Any kind of suggestion or help will be appreciated.